# Principle between Angular JS and Node js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I wanted to know if it is mandatory to use a template engine (EJS, Jade,...)
if i work with Angular JS and Node.js

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
app.set('view engine','jade');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer : No.

You most likely won't need to have a server side template engine since your views (and the data in them) are handled by AngularJs client side.

Comment: F after how to send the object to the HTML page 
res.render () ??

Comment: That's a whole other subject but generally you do it through `$http` using ajax. (or `$resource` if your server is RESTful)

Answer (score 0):

No, its absolutely not mandatory, but since working with angular, we use jade as templating engine. Simply because it is so much faster to write and (in my humble opinion) easier to read.

greetings